# Trying to write Php fwrite XML file from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, xml, fwrite

I am trying to write some code that grabs a CSV file pulls the relevant postcode column then looks up that postcode in a MySql database which has longitude and latitude fields then save them to an XML file so it can be used in a different program

I think this code piece is all working, but for some reason, it only outputs the last field of the query :

```
//Open the file.
$fileHandle = fopen("test.csv", "r");
$postcode = array();
while (($row = fgetcsv($fileHandle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
 array_push($postcode, $row[40]);
}
$postcodefil = (array_unique($postcode));
$postcodefil = str_replace(' ', '', $postcodefil);
$postcodefil = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $postcodefil);
//print_r($postcodefil);
foreach ($postcodefil as $value) {
  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,   $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }
  $sql = "SELECT postcode, latitude, longitude  FROM postcode WHERE postcode='$value' ";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $myfile = fopen("test.xml", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $lat = $row["latitude"];
        $lng = $row["longitude"];
        fwrite($myfile, $lat."testss".$lng."\n");
        echo $lat;
        echo $lng;
        echo "<br />";
        }}
} // end of foreach
$conn->close();
```

however when i run it, it echo's correctly

```
50.822398-0.139938
51.444908-1.295341
50.841951-0.842508
51.308504-0.551835
etc.... etc...
```

but the Fwrite just outputs the last line

```
51.120916testss-0.599545
```

I' m totally confused by this. Please forgive me if it's something basic that I've over looked and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you open the file in each loop, this overwrites the previous data...

```
   $myfile = fopen("test.xml", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

So move the open outside the loop.

The second issue is that you aren't writing XML at all.  You need to do something like...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string("<coords />");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $newCoord = $xml->addChild("coord");
    $newCoord->addChild("latitude", $row["latitude"]);
    $newCoord->addChild("longitude", $row["longitude"]);
}
$xml->saveXML("test.xml");
```

This will generate a simple XML file, you will need to set the element names as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

First thing put the connection outside of the foreach loop, and the fopen outside the while 
loop.

You open the xml file in the 'w' mode means according to the doc

> Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the
>   file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist,
>   attempt to create it.

You need append mode 'a'

> Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the file.
>   If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. In this mode,
>   fseek() has no effect, writes are always appended.

This will work for you. But you still making a db request per postalcode, i would suggest to collect all the postal code you need to query and make one db request to database with sql [IN](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php) operator.